# Programming Help-Finding and Printing multiples

Tags: java

if a input a number, how do i count the multiples of that inputted number until 100. 
For example if i input the number 8 
It would print out 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96

Comment: You can use a for loop.

Comment: You must show the code you have tried to accomplish this, and describe what problems you are having. Please show more effort while asking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show what you have tried so far. Please show us your attempt at solving the problem rather than simply telling us what your assignment is.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify a `for loop` very nicely so that it only increments by the number that you want. The upside is that it is not only easy to follow, and shorter, but it is also more efficient. Don't loop more times than you need. Keep it simple.

Eg

```
int n = 8;//your chosen number (however you decide to get it)
for (int x = n; x <= 100;x+=n) 
{
  System.out.println (x);
}
```

What we have done:
made an `int n` holding the number that the user wants to increment by.
Then in the for loop, we:

- Made the for loop variable,`x` equal to `n`.
- Made the condition that the loop must break once `x` reaches or passes `100`
- Tell the loop to increase `x` by `n` for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) starting from 8, and at each iteration add 8 to the current number. I let you fill up the `???` :

```
for (???; value <= 100; ???) {
    System.out.print(value);
}
```

Here's also a one-liner using java 8 :

```
IntStream.iterate(8, i -> i+8).limit(100/8).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int i         = n;

System.out.println("Enter number: ");
int n = input.nextInt();

while (true) {
   System.out.println(i);
   i += n;
   if (i > 100) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int input = 8;
int result = input;
while(result < 100){
    System.out.println(result);
    result += input;
}
```

Comment: wat is input initalized as?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way is to use a for loop

```
public static void printMultiples(int k) {    
    boolean isHead = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i % k == 0) {
            if (isHead) {
                System.out.print(i);
                isHead = false;
            }
            else System.out.print(", " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. It will not use java 8, as that is very new, so its not recommended.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("You must enter at least one number!");
        }

        int originalNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int number = originalNumber * 1; // For avoiding pointer problems
        while((number + originalNumber) > 100) {
            System.out.println(number);
            number += originalNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the modulo operator `%`:

```
if (n % 8 == 0) {
     System.out.println(n);
}
```

This means: if the remainder of dividing `n` by `8` is equal to `0`, we should print this number.

Comment: private static String getMultiples(int divisor, int N){
  
  String multiples = "";
  System.out.println("Multiples for " + N + "are");
  while ((N > 0) || (N < 100)){
   if (N > 0){
   multiples = (N );
   divisor++;
   }
  }
  
  
  
  return multiples;
 }

Comment: This might not be a good solution because you could always sum 8 and thus n % 8 == 0 is always true

Comment: if (n % 8 == 0) {
     System.out.println(n);
} what does "n" = in this situation